# Jquery .post() not passing data to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, post

I am trying to pass an array through post to a php file. Here is my function in jQuery:

```
function callPHP() {
  $.post("php/save.php", {
      node: node
    },
    function (responde) {
      console.log(responde);
    });
}
```

And my `save.php` file has following content:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['node'];
?>
```

But I get an error that there's an undefined index 'node'. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: node is another variable? or string?

Comment: Is node a variable? If you change it to : "node", it should get passed as a string. If you want to pass an object just make sure the variable is declared and set up how you want already.

Comment: Are you sure `node` is available in the scope of the function? You should do a `console.log(node);` and post the results here.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, which suggests a difference in our setups. What version of jQuery are you using? Can you do a `print_r($GLOBALS)` in save.php when you've posted to it and show us the output?

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
     //define php info and make ajax call
     $.ajax({
         url: "php/save.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: { node: node },
         cache: false,
         success: function (response) {

         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below example. where `info` is an array

```
 info = [];
 info[0] = 'hi';
 info[1] = 'hello';


 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {info:info},
    url: "index.php",
    success: function(msg){
     $('.answer').html(msg);
    }
  });
```

`.answer` is the class of the element where you want to output your answer.